# How to escape a period in mySql JSON query

Tags: mysql, json, database, mysql-workbench, mysql-json

I am working on a project where i am required to store data in JSON format using mySQL DB.
I want to store data in this format:

```
{
 email1:{ data:"This is some data of email1", status:"registered", count:100 },
 email1:{ data:"This is some data of email2", status:"unregistered", count:230 },
}
```

Here email1 & email2 are two emails of someone acting as a key. while executing queries to store and retrieve data in this format, i discovered that emails could contain periods in them too, for example: *max.jhon@gmail.com* or *master.blaster01@gmail.com*.

And due to presence of period in keys i am unable to execute json queries in DB. Like:
`SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(analytics, "$.max.jhon@gmail.com") FROM EmailsData;` Does not work due to presence of periods in **$.max.jhon@gmail.com** and give me this error :

> Error Code: 3143. Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around
> character position 8.

Can someone suggest me how can i escape these periods inside query and if not then what will be best way to store data in JSON format for respective emails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use single quotes similar to the following:

```
'$."max.jhon@gmail.com"'
```

Please give it try.